# CSS @keyframe animation ease-out

Tags: css, animation, hover, keyframe

I'm trying to make an animation ease out to element's original values after hover off. The animation itself works fine,
but when I hover off of the element, it reverts to it's original state **instantly**, whereas I'd like to have a 0.2s **ease out**. Any help?

Here's my code:

```
img.footer {
        filter: grayscale(1);
        -webkit-filter: grayscale(1);
        animation-timing-function: ease-out; /*this is what i have tried*/
        -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out; /*this is what i have tried*/
    }
    @keyframes flash {
        0%   {
            filter: grayscale(1);
            -webkit-filter: grayscale(1);
        }
        6%   {
            filter: grayscale(0) brightness(1.2);
            -webkit-filter: grayscale(0) brightness(1.2);
        }
        33%, 100%   {
            filter: grayscale(0) brightness(1);
            -webkit-filter: grayscale(0) brightness(1);
        }
    }
    img.footer:hover {
        animation-name: flash;
        animation-duration: 0.999s;
        animation-fill-mode: forwards;
        animation-timing-function: ease-out; /*this is what i have tried*/
        -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out; /*this is what i have tried*/
    }
```

[Working sample](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OzVPJb)

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OzVPJb

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to apply it with just transition effects for the start and end states, where the non-hover css is the desired initial state and transition from hover:

```
img.footer {
  filter: grayscale(1);
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(1);
  -moz-transition:all 0.2s ease;
    -webkit-transition:all 0.2s ease;
    -ms-transition:all 0.2s ease;
    -o-transition:all 0.2s ease;
    transition:all 0.2s ease;
}
img.footer:hover {
  filter: grayscale(0) brightness(1.2);
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(0) brightness(1.2);
  -moz-transition:all 0.999s ease;
    -webkit-transition:all 0.999s ease;
    -ms-transition:all 0.999s ease;
    -o-transition:all 0.999s ease;
    transition:all 0.999s ease;
}
```

The only caveat to this approach is you can't specify the intermediate grayscale or brightness values (if you don't want a linear transition).

Comment: That's the point, the brightness value keyframe 6% is the one I'm trying to get to work. The element regains color and flashes on hover (6%), then brightness goes back to 1 and grayscale stays at 0 from 33 to 100% keyframe. If I take out the flash (brightness 1.2) keyframe 6%, it becomes a simple hover transition which is pretty straight forward.

Comment: you may need to use javascript then to set the animation transition out

Comment: So is there no pure CSS solution?

Comment: Not that I am aware of or have seen.